# How to disable a textbox while when we hit edit option in edit.cshtml page in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, edit

====> Here is my edit.cshtml page code:

```
         <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Eno, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Eno, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Eno, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to disable this textbox. Can anyone help me with that.

This is my Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Models.Employee e1 = new Models.Employee();
        e1.Eno = id;
        e1 = objdalemp.SearchEmp(e1);
        return View(e1);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Models.Employee e1)
    {
        int i = objdalemp.UpdateEmployee(e1);
        if(i==1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(e1);
    }
```

Comment: You want to disable editor for everytime ?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable a html field generated using the following

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Eno, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } }).
```

Comment: I tried with this, it's working, but the issue is it is throwing an error like "Eno" which was not supplied.

Comment: @Nani Did not understand the error you are facing? Is it possible to add a bit more context?

Comment: Dear @Tej when I add "disabled" the option is disabling properly, but when i try to save the other details like name, salary etc , it is displaying like "Eno" is empty means it is passing as 0. It is not passing the original value.

Comment: If I disable like that, the value will not be passed

Comment: If you disable a field, you need to add a hidden field with the same value so when posting, it will get the current value in the post data.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable like below.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Eno, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled ="true", @class = "form-control" } })
```